# Como não atualizar campos vazios

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Gostaria de **não** atualizar os valores enviados como vazio, como o segundo argumento passado de exemplo abaixo, porém  quero evitar a utilização de um IF, não sei se o mysql proporciona alguma função que pode me ajudar

Chamada da proc de exemplo:

```
call AtualizarCadastro('Valor1', '', 'DoutorPinpolho', 4)
```

Proc criada abaixo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AtualizarCadastro`(in nome varchar(100), in sobrenome varchar(100), in senha varchar(100), in id int)
    BEGIN 

    UPDATE UsuariosLogin SET 

     `Nome`   nome
     `Sobrenome`   = sobrenome
     `Senha`   = senha

    where IdUsuario = id;

    END
```

Comment: geralmente essa validação não é feita no banco e sim no seu back-end, antes da chamada da procedure

Comment: Sim, porém não quero fazer esta validação, e como o banco possui sua própria linguagem acredito que ele possa fazer isso nativamente, já que é um tratamento mais especifico de dados para o banco

Answer (score 1):

```
COALESCE(valor, ...)
```

Retorna o primeiro valor não NULL da lista de valores. Se não houver nenhum valor diferente de NULL então retornará NULL.

Pode ser, por exemplo:

```
COALESCE(valor, 'Não informado')
```

Comment: Mas vamos supor que eu tenho um campo com senha e este campo vem vazio de um formulário, só que se o cara não coloca a senha ele vai permanecer em branco, mas no banco a senha já é existente, mas como é formulário de atualização a senha não aparece mas se ele quiser mudar ele tem que preencher, ou seja, a função vai ficar sem a senha e quando for assim eu quero que o campo permaneça o que já está no banco, deu para compreender?

Comment: Neste caso coloque 3 valores: a senha informada, a senha já existente (que você recuperou da tabela) e por último a informação de não informada.

Comment: Mas é justamente o que eu não quero fazer, eu quero apenas realizar todo esse fluxo apenas, mas apenas por banco, por isso não envolvi nada no backend na pergunta

Comment: Como não envolver backend????

Comment: Você pede para envolver o back, porque você talvez só conheça backend, mas quem conhece SQL vai saber em sql, e simplesmente não quero envolver, quero resolver esta situação, se fosse de outra forma com backend eu também não teria a necessidade de perguntar no stackoverflow

Comment: Ma aonde você pretende fazer um UPDATE de sua base de dados senão no backend?

Comment: Ele já recupera o valor da model, porém só não recupero a senha

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Update tabela
set coluna = coalesce(valorParametro, coluna)
Where IdUsuario = id;
```

Comment: Não ficou compreensivo, "valorColuna"???

Comment: Nome genérico pra coluna da tabela. Vou renomear pra ficar mais compreensível

Comment: Testei agora e não funcionou

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `USP_AtualizarCadastroPaciente`(in nome varchar(100), in sobrenome varchar(100), in senha varchar(100), in id int)
BEGIN 

UPDATE UsuariosLogin SET 

 `Nome`   = sobrenome,
 `Sobrenome`   = sobrenome,
 `Senha`   = Coalesce(senha, `Senha`)

where IdUsuario = id;
END